# Drag and drop to Spotify app icon

Tags: api, drag-and-drop, icons, spotify

I'm making a Spotify app and I want to be able to drop something onto the app icon. There are examples of dropping things to the app, but how do I get the icon to react to dropping?

Adding the event listener

```
models.application.addEventListener('dropped', function() {
  doSomething();
});
```

doesn't seem to do it. Other apps have it though, so there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`AcceptedLinkTypes`](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#applicationmanifest) attribute to the `manifest.json` file of your Spotify app.

For instance, if your app wants to react to drag&drop of playlists, you would do:

```
{
    "AcceptedLinkTypes": ["playlist"],
    ...
}
```

Currently, `album`, `artist`, `playlist`, `track` and `user` are supported.

If the changes in AcceptedLinkTypes don't take any effect, try restarting the client.

Comment: In case it happens to others, I'll note that I had to restart Spotify to get changes to AcceptedLinkTypes to take effect, reloading the application was not sufficient

Comment: @Thomas I have edited the answer to include your comment. Thanks!